# Will the standard library of C++ contains networking, string algorithms,... in future?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I had to start using C++ in my work and actually, I started to like it. And thanks to Scott Meyers's books it is not that hard to get into it. But I hate the lack of features (not) contained in the standard library. Will there be a similar set of functions like (for example) in the D's Phobos library (https://dlang.org/phobos/) in future?

Why there are no methods for working with strings, JSON, TCP/IP, features for dealing with arrays? I already found some papers about networking and so on, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental. But will these features actually get into the <del>STL</del> standard library? If so - when?

**Note**: I'm aware of Boost framework. Are there any discussions about merging it into the standard library?

Comment: The term `STL` only refers to the *containers* and *algorithms* part of the standard library, so no networking there :)

Comment: Hmm, let's see if `boost::asio` will make it into the standards.

Comment: I've given up waiting and now treat boost as the standard library. Having said that, having spoken a few times to the author and maintainer of asio, I think it has a chance of getting into c++20. c++17 has some languages fixes that make future continuations legal (the current boost implementations use implementation-defined features).
I remember there being talk of a standard graphics library back in 2012, but have seen nothing more of it. That's a shame and an error in my view.

Comment: What  C++ really needs is not a bloated standard library, but a standardized package management system, so that using third party libraries would not be such a pain.

Comment: @RichardHodges The 2D graphics proposal is http://wg21.link/p0267

Comment: @yurikilochek for package management, cmake and hunter (https://github.com/ruslo/hunter) have solved most of my concerns. I disagree about the need for a large standard library. 3rd party open source can't always be trusted to be maintained or even compatible between releases. A focussed effort on a standard library for presentation solves most of the barriers to entry for new developers - after all, nearly all of them would like to create games.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ standard library has introduced some features that originally started in Boost, like shared pointers for instance, so there is chance that this transfer will continue in future.

C++11 already introduced some string manipulation methods. As for C++17, it is planned to introduce, among others, filesystem and variant (now both part of boost). C++20 may contain networking extensions:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4656.pdf